# Can the default for 'remind me at location' be changed to 'Arriving' in Reminders.app?

Tags: macos, reminders

When you create a location based reminder in Reminders.app, you are given two options to trigger the alert: 'Leaving' and 'Arriving'.

I don't know if this is uncommon, but I have never needed the 'Leaving' option. When I use a location based reminders is often related to things I need to do, people to talk, or things to pick up *at* that location. A reminder when I leave is not exactly useful for those kinds of tasks.

Anyway, the problem is that I'm sick of having to manually change the selection to 'Arriving' for every reminder.

Do you know if there is a way to somehow change the default to be always 'Arriving'?

I'm on Yosemite 10.10.5.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

I just upgraded to OS X 10.11 El Capitan, and found out that the default has been changed to "Arriving" for location based reminders.

So it seems it was not just me..